# Making the number 12345...n

Tags: code-request, number-theory, number-representation, prime-numbers, big-numbers

Well, I am trying to write a code that makes the number:

$$123456\dots n\tag1$$

So, when $n=10$ we get:

$$12345678910$$

And when $n=15$ we get:

$$123456789101112131415$$

And when $n=4$ we get:

$$1234$$

Comment: Maybe not very practical for construction, but it may be noteworthy that `ChampernowneNumber[]` is related to this.

Comment: ^ e.g `IntegerPart[ChampernowneNumber[10] 10^31]`

Comment: @flinty The messy part is the exponent of the multiplier...

Comment: @kirma If you are curious about it, the exponent is a combination of `Log[10, ...]`s and `Floor[...]`s, see my answer below.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
FromDigits@Flatten[IntegerDigits /@ Range[15]]

123456789101112131415
```

A function to do it:

```
numberFromRange[n_] := FromDigits@Flatten[IntegerDigits /@ Range@n]
```

Answer (score 10):

```
f1 = FromDigits @ StringRiffle[Range[#], ""] &;

f1 /@ {4, 10, 15}
```

> ```
> {1234, 12345678910, 123456789101112131415}
> ```

And

```
f2 = FromDigits @* StringJoin @* IntegerString @* Range;

f2 /@ {4, 10, 15}
```

> ```
> {1234, 12345678910, 123456789101112131415}
> ```

A variation on @user1066's answer:

```
f3 = Array[IntegerString, #, 1, FromDigits @* StringJoin] &;

f3 /@ {5, 10, 15}
```

> ```
> {12345, 12345678910, 123456789101112131415}
> ```

Answer (score 8):

Without using `IntegerDigits` or string processing:

```
f[x_] := Last@NestWhile[#[[1]]+{1,#[[2]]*10^IntegerLength@#[[1]]}&,{1,0},#[[1]]<=x&]
```

```
f[105]
(* 1234567891011121314151617181920212223242526272829303132333435363738394
0414243444546474849505152535455565758596061626364656667686970717273747
5767778798081828384858687888990919293949596979899100101102103104105 *)
```

Answer (score 5):

```
ToExpression[
  StringJoin[
    ToString /@ Range[15]
  ]
]
```

Answer (score 5):

For fun, here's some more options, which are quite distinct from the already existing ones.

First, a recursive definition:

```
f[1] = 1;
f[n_] := f[n] = f[n - 1]*10^Floor[Log[10, 10*n]] + n
```

And, second, one using [kirma](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/3056/kirma)'s and [flinty](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/72682/flinty)'s suggestion, i.e., the [Champernowne constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Champernowne_constant):

```
f[n_] := IntegerPart[ChampernowneNumber[10] 10^((n + 1) Floor[Log[10, 10*n]] - (10^Floor[Log[10, 10*n]] - 1)/(10 - 1))]
```

They both yield the same answer as other posts, naturally.

For more info, see [OEIS](https://oeis.org/A007908).

Comment: Thanks, I like them! Merry Christmas

Answer (score 5):

Timings for all the methods ([g1 : murray](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/261159/125), [g2 : flinty](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/261167/125), [g3/g4 : AccidentalFourierTransform](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/261188/125), [g5/g6 : Syed](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/261162/125), [g7 : David Reiss](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/261176/125), [g8 : user1066](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/261210/125), [g9/g10/g11 : kglr](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/261158/125)) posted so far:

```
ClearAll[g1, g2, g3, g4, g5, g6, g7, g8, g9, g10, g11, funcs]

g1 = FromDigits @ Flatten[IntegerDigits /@ Range[#]] &;

g2[x_] := Last @ NestWhile[#[[1]] + {1, #[[2]]*10^IntegerLength@#[[1]]} &, {1, 
    0}, #[[1]] <= x &]

g3[1] = 1;
g3[n_] := Block[{$RecursionLimit = 10^6}, g3[n] = g3[n - 1]*10^Floor[Log[10, 10*n]] + n]

g4 = IntegerPart[ChampernowneNumber[10] 
       10^((# + 1) Floor[Log[10, 10*#]] - (10^Floor[Log[10, 10*#]] - 1)/(10 - 1))] &;

g5 = FromDigits @* Flatten @* IntegerDigits @* Range @ # &;

g6 = FromDigits @ Flatten @ Last @ Reap @ Scan[Sow[IntegerDigits[#]] &] @ Range[#] &;

g7 = ToExpression[StringJoin[ToString /@ Range[#]]] &;

g8 = ToExpression @ StringJoin @ Array[IntegerString, #] &;

g9 = FromDigits @* StringJoin @* IntegerString @* Range;

g10 = Array[IntegerString, #, 1, FromDigits @* StringJoin] &;

g11 = FromDigits @ StringRiffle[Range[#], ""] &;

funcs = {g1, g2, g3, g4, g5, g6, g7, g8, g9, g10, g11};
```

**Timings:**

```
ClearAll[res, timing]
Do[timing[i] = First[RepeatedTiming[
    res[i] = funcs[[i]] /@ {5, 15, 55, 105, 1005, 10005}]], {i, 1, 11}]

Equal @@ (res /@ Range[11])
```

> ```
> True
> ```

```
replace = {g2 -> "Last@NestWhile[#[[1]]+{1,#[[2]]*10^IntegerLength@#[[1]]}&,{1,0},#[[1]]\[LessEqual]x&]", 
   g3 -> "g3[1]=1;
    g3[n_]:=Block[{$RecursionLimit=10^6},g3[n]=g3[n-1]*10^Floor[Log[10,10*n]]+n]"};

MapIndexed[{"g" <> ToString@#2[[1]], # /. replace, timing[#2[[1]]]} &][funcs] // 
  SortBy[Last] // 
  Prepend[{"function", "definition", "timing"}] // 
  Grid[#, Alignment -> {{Center, Left, "."}, Center}, Dividers -> All] &
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, for the tremendous effort. I really like it and it gave me a ton of insight into the problem. Merry Christmas

Answer (score 4):

Identical to the solution by @murray but written as a composition:

```
f = FromDigits@*
    Flatten@*
    IntegerDigits@*
    Range@
   # &

f /@ Range[8, 15]
```

---

Using Reap/Sow:

```
g = FromDigits@
   Flatten@Last@Reap@Scan[Sow[IntegerDigits[#]] & ]@Range[#] &

g /@ Range[8, 15]
```

---

Result:

> ```
> {12345678, 123456789, 12345678910, 1234567891011, 123456789101112, \
> 12345678910111213, 1234567891011121314, 123456789101112131415}
> ```

Answer (score 2):

```
ToExpression@StringJoin@Array[IntegerString,15]
(* 123456789101112131415 *)
```

Comment: Thanks, I like it! Merry Christmas